# How to prevent a webkit-scrollbar from pushing over the contents of a div?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm using webkit-scrollbar and am running into styling issues as the webkit scrollbar is pushing the contents of a div to the left which causes the contents to overflow.

Notice

- 1st box uses the default browser scrollbar and does not overflow (good)
- 2nd box uses the webkit scrollbar which ends up breaking the layout. (bad/problem)

http://jsfiddle.net/ryeah/1/

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong with webkit scrollbar to cause the div to/overflow. How can we fix the 2nd box? Thanks

**Webkit Scrollbar Code:**

```
.box2::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 16px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 16px;
}
.box2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 6px;
    min-height: 28px;
    padding: 100px 0 0;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1),inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
}
.box2::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.box2::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 0 4px;
}
.box2::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: would you mind updating the accepted answer to the higher-rated one below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm.. I can't think of a way to get the webkit scrollbar in overlay. One solution to stop the line breaking is to hide the scrollbar with

```
.box2::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 16px;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 16px;
  display: none;
}
```

other you can set the width of your UL to the same as the box so it makes use of the overflow function and displays under the scrollbar

```
.box ul {
  width: 149px;
}
```

Answer (score 96):

2023: `overflow-y:overlay` is deprecated

---

Did you try putting `overflow-y:overlay` in the parent div? It works for me in chrome. [This page](http://help.dottoro.com/lcawqfhe.php) says it works in safari, too.

Comment: seem's this should be the selected answer here. Works perfectly

Comment: Elegant solution. Like @EidanSpiegel said though, not working in Firefox.

Comment: But the overlay is not transparent and a vertical scrollbar will block out any content that it overlays. Haven't found a way to make it transparent.

Comment: In my case, changing to `overflow-y:overlay` fixes Chrome and breaks Firefox.

Comment: Overflow: overlay is deprecated and doesn't work on Chrome anymore. Unfortunally, the alternative "scollbar-gutter" doesn't accomplish the same.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I made it work on Chrome, and **not break** Firefox:

```
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: overlay;
```

I mean, the scroll bar is still taking `width` space on Firefox, but at least it's still showing and working.

By just doing `overflow-y: overlay;`, I was fixing Chrome and breaking my Firefox scroll.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had the same issue and couldn't understand what was wrong with my simple flexbox code.

Comment: Also, I've added -moz to overflow-y: overlay.

Comment: It works in webkit browsers but it is quite ugly in Firefox because the scrollbar area appears even the content is small and not needed scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the scroll bar to display outside the div.

Use a static width and have the div position as absolute. Works for me.

```
#divID{
overflow: hidden;
width: calc(1024px + 0);
}

#divID:hover{
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

This fools the DOM.