# How can you prevent ::-webkit-scrollbar from pushing over elements

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm attempting to use webkit's custom scrollbar and I'd really like to prevent it from pushing over the div's next to it. I've tried hacking it by using an image sprite positioned to the right, but it goes under the scrollbar's trackbar. I've also attempted to hide the trackbar, set the opacity, negative margins/padding, and z-index—nothing appears to be working.

The desired effect would be to have the element (grey bar in image below) to continue to the edge of the container and not stop at the scrollbar track.

**How can you prevent ::-webkit-scrollbar from pushing over elements?**

[image: here]

*The [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054797/how-to-prevent-a-webkit-scrollbar-from-pushing-over-the-contents-of-a-div) has been asked, but no proper answer has been found yet (do not flag as a duplicate).*

Comment: @JoshCampbell no it can't. Doesn't seem to react to much of anything besides `background-color`, `width` and `box-shadow`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done by `overflow: overlay`. It is alternative for `overflow: auto`

Comment: As a sidenote, you may also had to deal with `overflow-x` in some cases (I had to when wrapping the entire app body, to deal with the overlay "offset" that permitted sideways scrolling by the scrollbar's width)