# Why does an overflow:auto scrollbar take width out of my div?

Tags: html, css

I have an absolutely positioned `div`, with `overflow:auto`.

When it overflows vertically, a vertical scrollbar appears. This appears within my `div` (even though it isn't fixed width), which shrinks the space available to the div's contents. In my case, it causes the text to wrap unnecessarily, which is undesirable.

See https://jsfiddle.net/hktgcrj0/ - shrink the page until the `div` overflows and the scroll bar appears - you will see the text wrap.

Is there any way to make the scrollbar appear *outside* of the `div`, or increase the width of the `div` to accommodate the scroll bar?

Note that for my application (the fiddle is massively simplified) giving the div a fixed width is not an option, and disabling text wrapping is also not an option.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054797/how-to-prevent-a-webkit-scrollbar-from-pushing-over-the-contents-of-a-div

Comment: @jfrej i dont think it is related.
check question he is asking that he dont want to use any fixed number for width.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

`div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}`

or wrap the inner elements in `<p>` tags and apply `white-space: nowrap;` to that.

Comment: I did say that disabling text wrapping is not an option.

Comment: You want the text to wrap, but not based on the additional space occupied by the scrollbar? I guess I'm unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve - if the scrollbar is outside of the div, it will be hidden when the window width is equal to the width of the div..

Comment: The div will have a maximum size dictated by some other constraints. When it hits that max I would want the text to wrap. However unless the div is hitting that maximum, I would not want the code to wrap. Does that help? If what I'm asking for is stupid, then I'm happy for someone to point that out.

Comment: I don't believe it's just stupid, but I'm not sure about the viability - the scrollbar isn't an exact width, it's different on every browser, and behaves differently on mobile, etc. Perhaps flexbox can offer a solution? http://bennettfeely.com/flexplorer/